# Write in an input content in a <dd> after a <dt> whose label is 'WRITE IN DD'

Tags: jquery

I would like to write or to put a value in an input content in  after a  whose label value is "WRITE IN DD".
Do you know how to do?

```
<dl class="last">
    <dt>
        <label>WRITE IN DD</label>
    </dt>
    <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"
                   id="options_13_text" class="input-text product-custom-option"
                   name="options[13]" value="">
        </div>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

Thanks for all

Comment: Please clarify the question

Answer (score 5):

```
$('label:contains("WRITE IN DD")').closest('dt').next().find('input').val('x')
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G3YSa/)**

Comment: Whilst this looks like it might be the *exact* answer he's looking for, perhaps you should suggest a DOM change as well because this approach looks uber dirty.

Comment: @IanClark - I see no reason to change the DOM here.

Comment: What is dirty about finding the label's parent's sibling's input field?